# Redirect works offline but not online

Tags: php

I have bellow code which works fine in localhost now that i have uploaded it online and page redirect fails after adding anything it shows only the first echo command and nothing further. Please help.

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
echo "<span class='notification n-information'>Welcome to '".strtoupper($_SESSION['user'])."' Admin Panel</span>"; 
  if($_SESSION['uid']==true){
      if($_SESSION['roles']==2 or $_SESSION['roles']==1){
      }elseif($_SESSION['roles']==3){
      header('Location:../a/index.php?action=NOT Allowed');
      }elseif($_SESSION['roles']==4){
      header('Location:../b/index.php?action=NOT Allowed');
      }elseif($_SESSION['roles']==5){
      header('Location:../c/index.php?action=NOT Allowed');
      }
      }else{
        header('Location:../index.php');  
  }
@require('quick.php');
@require('../conn/include.php');

$title=($_POST['title']);
$project=($_POST['project']);
$descrip=($_POST['description']);
if(isset($_REQUEST['add'])) { 
    $add="Insert into projects(project_name,title,details)VALUE('$project','$title','$descrip')";
    //echo "$add";
    $addquery=mysql_query($add);
    header('location:Projects.php');
    exit();
}

?>
```

My form action="" since i am redirecting it to same page

Answer (score 0):

try renaming `Projects.php` to `projects.php`,
because if you are using a `linux server` than these servers are `case sensitive` in file names..
 and also try removing `@` from `required`..

Comment: ohh ok.. and why you have taken `round brackets` for `$_POST variables` try removing these `round brackets`...
and which method you have used to send the `add` data.. wether it is `$_GET` or `$_POST`... try replacing `$_REQUEST` with the same

Comment: and try echo something in your last `if condition` check wether it is going in your `if condition` or not...

Answer (score 0):

The `Location` header must be echoed *before* any other content (e.g. your `span` tag). Otherwise, your browser will ignore the header and will display whatever content you've already echoed + whatever else your script echoes before it terminates.

Additionally: when the condition is met to send the redirection request, go ahead and end rest of the script's execution with an `exit;` or `die()` statement.

This should work:

```
if($_SESSION['uid']==true){
    if ($_SESSION['roles'] != 1 and $_SESSION['roles'] != 2)
    {
        switch($_SESSION['roles'])
        {
            case 3:
            $url = "../a/index.php?action=NOT Allowed";
            break;
            case 4:
            $url = "../b/index.php?action=NOT Allowed";
            break;
            case 5:
            $url = "../c/index.php?action=NOT Allowed";
            break;
            default:
            $url = "../index.php";
        }
        header('Location:'.$url);
        die();
    }
}

echo "<span class='notification n-information'>Welcome to '".strtoupper($_SESSION['user'])."' Admin Panel</span>";
```